# MethodInfo.Invoke requires admin on windows 7?

Tags: c#, windows-7, invoke, administration, methodinfo

So I am loading an assembly at runtime and I also am using generics depending on the assembly type.  To get the right type, each DLL is implementing a factory that I expect to be there which instantiates the class with the correct generic type.

```
            Type factoryType = assembly.GetType("MyCompany.ScenarioPlayer.PlayerFactory");
            MethodInfo method = factoryType.GetMethod("CreatePlayer", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

            player = (IScenarioPlayer)method.Invoke(null, null);
```

This code fails on the method.Invoke when I don't have administrative privileges. Is this correct that any calls to MethodInfo.Invoke the way I'm using it requires admin?  I stepped down into my DLL's code and it isn't even getting past this call into the Factory.

edit : turns out there was a dependency for the target DLL that was not accounted for.  I do like the MEF framework idea proposed though.

Comment: Post the exception message and stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with MethodInfo, but rather what MethodInfo is doing most likely.  You can test this out by calling the method in question and seeing if it works in a non admin environment.

Comment: This is what actually helped me solve my issue even though it's one of the first things I SHOULD have done.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using reflection, in the way you're using it, to solve the problem of creating factories at runtime is a bad idea. Not only are you *not* avoid coupling (you've got a hard-coded string referencing a single type), you're opening up a world of hurt. None of this stuff is strongly typed.

I would suggest looking at something like [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) if you're looking to create pluggable components. It already solves the problems you're facing *and* is does it in a much nicer, faster and more maintainable way.